# Sketch exports Alpha Mask different to a PDF than to a PNG?

Tags: pdf, export, png, sketch-app, gradient

I'm using [Sketch](http://sketchapp.com/) to make a fade out effect in an image using a gradient alpha mask as described at the bottom of [this page](http://www.sketchapp.com/learn/documentation/04-shapes/4-masking.html). In Sketch it looks like I want it to, and now I want to export it both to a PNG and a PDF. Exporting to PNG works fine:

[image]

I now also wanted to export it to PDF, but now the image suddenly also fades at the top:

[image]

Does anybody know why this is, and does anybody know how I can export this to PDF correctly? All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transparent gradients are [not supported](https://www.sketchapp.com/learn/documentation/11-exporting/3-file-formats.html) in PDF. There is no neat solution to this problem, what you could try and do is flatten the gradients to bitmaps before exporting.

To do this, go to **Layer > Flatten selection to bitmap.**

Comment: Man, what a bummer that this is the only solution.